# Objective-Cの「Please import the NetworkExtension module instead of this file directly.」エラーについて

Tags: objective-c, xcode12

Networkframeworkの以下のクラスをObjective-Cで試そうとしています。

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neapppushmanager?language=objc

Test.h

```
#ifndef Test_h
#define Test_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import NetworkExtension※１
#import <NetworkExtension/NEAppPushManager.h>※２

@interface Test : NSObject
@end

#endif /* Test_h */
```

Test.m

```
#import "Test.h"

@implementation Test

- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        
        if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
            [NEAppPushManager loadAllFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<NEAppPushManager *> * _Nullable managers, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"Load Error: %@", error.description);
                }
                
                NEAppPushManager *manager;
                if (managers.count > 0) {
                    manager = managers[0];
                }else {
                    manager = [[NEAppPushManager alloc] init];
                }
                
                //... your code here...
            }];
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        
            
        
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

※２としていたのですが、
`「Please import the NetworkExtension module instead of this file directly.」`というエラーが発生したため、
NetworkExtensionのモジュールを直接インポートするような内容であったため※１に変更したところ、
`「Use of '@import' when modules are disabled」`のエラーが出ております。
上記について、Build Settings->Apple Clang - Language - ModulesのEnable Modules(C and Objective-C)の設定がNoとなっていたのでYesに変更したのですが、上記エラーが解消されません。

何か他に変更がいるのでしょうか？
そもそも※１のエラーの解釈が間違っていますでしょうか？

Xcode：12.4

Comment: ご質問中の2ファイルは一体どのようなプロジェクトに付け加えられたのでしょうか?通常のiOSアプリでもiOSフレームワーでも上記の※1(`;`が必要ですが)※2とも問題なくコンパイルできたのですが?

Comment: NetworkExtention.frameworkになります。（意味が違ったらすいません）また、；の話はTest.hの話で良いでしょうか？こちらは;がない状態で、記載のエラーが出ておりました

Comment: Xcode 12.4のプロジェクトテンプレートにはNetworkExtention.frameworkというのは存在しないのですが、Network Extensionターゲットのことでしょうか?すでに自己解決されたようですが、ご質問内容に問題点が再現できる十分な情報を入れてもらえると、他の方々にも参考になるだろうと思います。

Comment: Network Extensionターゲットとなります

Comment: ご確認ありがとうございました。残念ながら「Network Extensionターゲット」の場合でもご記載の事象が発生しませんでした。「古いXcodeで作ったプロジェクトで試している」「サードパーティ製のライブラリを使用している」「Xcodeのおすすめ設定とは異なる警告設定にしている」など、ご記載の事象が発生する条件になりうる事柄についてお気付きの点があれば、本文に追記していただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました！

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <NetworkExtension/NetworkExtension.h>
```

上記のimportでコンパイルできました。